# "Hash sum mismatch" error when doing apt-get update

Tags: apt, update-manager

Specific files are causing this error, like

```
Err:7 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages
```

`Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages`

I have tried all the solutions posted in similar questions, but it still seems to happen.

I've tried fixes from the following questions but still no luck:
[sudo apt-get update failes due to Hash Sum mismatch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760574/sudo-apt-get-update-failes-due-to-hash-sum-mismatch)

["hash sum mismatch" error when doing update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/846767/hash-sum-mismatch-error-when-doing-update)

["apt-get update" always failed to fetch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/711794/apt-get-update-always-failed-to-fetch)

Also I am behind a proxy, so I have added these lines to `etc/apt/apt.conf`

```
Acquire::http::proxy "http://<proxy>:<port>/";
Acquire::ftp::proxy "ftp://<proxy>:<port>/";
Acquire::https::proxy "https://<proxy>:<port>/";`
```

Comment: Strangely, the update happens when I run `sudo apt-get update` for the second time.

Comment: Ah, I just replied to your other post where you had the same issue but switching from `apt` to `apt-get` did fix the problem. Did you find any solution?

Comment: and I found a possible solution; added below.

Answer (score 0):

I have no good explanation for *why* this might work, but it just *did* for me, when I got these errors trying to do `sudo apt install emacs25` or `sudo apt-get install emacs25`. So in case it works for others:

This install of `emacs25/bionic,now 25.2+1-6 amd64` required several dependent packages, namely:

1. `emacs25-bin-common/bionic,now 25.2+1-6 amd64`
2. `emacs25-common/bionic,bionic,now 25.2+1-6 all`
3. `emacs25-el/bionic,bionic,now 25.2+1-6 all`
4. `emacsen-common/bionic,bionic,now 2.0.8 all`

I wanted to see if I could narrow down what the particular problem file was, since they were all throwing hash sum errors, so I tried to install `emacs25-common`. Same issue (though it had dependencies on all the other three numbered above).

Then I tried `sudo apt install emacs25-el`. This worked, and curiously, the first dependency *it* installed was `emacs25-common` — the one I'd just tried to install unsuccessfully. It installed `emacs25-common` and the other three packages (all except for `emacs25` itself) successfully.

Then I did `sudo apt install emacs25`. This, too, worked.

So this is voodoo, but I would suggest trying to install the dependencies separately first, trying different dependencies, until one does install, and then trying again.

My *guess* would be that something server-side was being cached, and breaking the normal order of requests resulted in a cache miss allowing the original file to be re-checksummed, but that's a total stab in the dark.

(After the above was done I was able to install the suggested package using `sudo apt install emacs25-common-non-dfsg` without issues.)